# Is this code, using (Mockito and JUnit) a good way to test a method getById from my @Service?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am using mockito to write some unit tests and I'm not sure if this test is satisfactory for method getById.

```
@Mock
private CustomerService customerService;

@Test
public void Customer_Get_By_ID() {
        Customer customer = Customer.builder()
                .firstName("Name")
                .lastName("Last Name")
                .email("name.last@mail.com")
                .build();
        Long customerId = customerService.create(customer);
        assertNotNull(customerId);

        when(customerService.get(customerId)).thenReturn(customer);
        Customer saved = customerService.get(customerId);
        assertEquals(saved.getFirstName(), customer.getFirstName());
        assertEquals(saved.getLastName(), customer.getLastName());
        verify(customerService, times(1)).get(customerId);
}
```

Is this test correct?
Any advice or another way to write this test?

Comment: What is the SUT here? What is useing  `customerService` as a collaborator so you have to mock it?

Comment: You are not testing the class you want to test, you are actually doing the opposite (skipping the object you wanted to test). Mockito is useful when you need to test an object that internally calls another object that you really don't want to execute. Let's say that your service internally calls a DAO, so... with mockito you can mock your dao to avoid calling the DB for real

Comment: Show the implementation of the SUT.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of mocking is that the method you want to test of your SUT (System under Test) depends on a collaborator that you can't set up for the test. So you *mock* this collaborator. Let

- `S` be the SUT
- `m()` be a method of SUT which you want to test
- `t` be a test method that creates an instance of `S` and calls `m()` on it
- `C` be a collaborator that `S` depends on
- `n()` be a a method on `C` that ist called inside `m()`.

Now let's assume that it is difficult to set up `C` so you want to mock it.

```java
interface C {
  String n();
}
```

```java
@Mock
private C cMock;
```

For your test method you instruct `cMock` to answer in a way that makes `m()` behave in a way you want to test.

```java
@Test
public void t() {
  when(cMock.n()).thenReturn("you've called n()");

  // S depends on a C.
  S sut = new S(cMock);

  // Execute the method of the SUT you want to test.
  String result = sut.m();

  // Verify the result.
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo("C said: you've called n()");

  // Optional: Verify that n() was called as expected.
  verify(cMock).n();
}
```

Since you are doing TDD (you are, aren't you?), you can now start to implement `m()`.

```java
public class S {
  C c;

  public S(C c) {
    this.c = c;
  }

  public String m() {
    // TODO implement me by calling c.n()
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lil' nitpick: SUT can also stand for system under test, but I guess "subject under test" is more suitable in the scope we work there :). But nice answer nontheless.